# How to put variables into HTML from ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I tried to use a variable in HTML which is calculated from ruby code and MSSQL

This is my Ruby code to get @result

```
class StartingController < ApplicationController

before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :start]

attr_reader :table
attr_writer :table

def initialize
@table = Hash.new()
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
@st='exec search '
end

def start
.... some code set @st values  
  @result = @connection.exec_query(@st)
  @table = @result[0]
  redirect_to '/results'
end
end

def index
end

def results
end

end
```

This is the HTML which need to use @result

```
<% @result.each do |x| %>
 <tr>
 s: <td><%= x %></td>

</tr>
<% end %>
```

But I always get

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

if I

```
puts @result
```

I can get correct value

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. Controllers aren't supposed to have an `initialize` method, and there's no need to use ActiveRecord::Base directly if you have a model. What reference are you basing this on? A good reference book on Rails should show you how to construct this properly.

Comment: I agree with @tadman, it is not a good idea for your controller to have an `initialize` method. Also, it looks like you are being redirected to `"/results"`, I would either have your `@results` variable being defined in the `results` action, OR change your `redirect_to '/results'` to `render :results`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the instance variables(and variables) only accessible within an action, and your `redirect_to` actually change the action from `start` to `results`, so `@results` is not initialized.

I assume that you have a view at `views/start/result.html.erb`.

The best solution for this is you can remove the action `results`, and call `render :results` instead of `redirect_to`.